# How to check the data completeness in ETL Testing

Tags: manual-testing, load-testing, database, etl

I am working on healthcare project. I need to verify the data present in staging tables, DWH tables and target tables. I am checking manually for few records but my management asking to look for a solution which solves to verify the data completeness for thousands or millions of records without a paid tool. Is it possible to check million records data...???

Comment: How are you checking it manually ? What are the attributes you use to confirm the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Given you're talking about "millions" it makes sense to use a load testing tool which can do multiple actions in parallel. If you don't have a better candidate yet you can consider [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which provides:

1. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  - so you can read "expected" data from file(s) in your local file system
2. [JDBC Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) sampler - to execute database queries
3. [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) - to apply custom pass/fail criteria, i.e. ensure that the data from CSV is in the DB
4. And perform it all with multiple threads, the number can be configured in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how complex the transformations are, if you can query both the input and the target tables than maybe a simple record count, a column sum and checking first, last and a row in the middle could be sufficient to tackle most risks.

> Checking Data Completeness is done to verify that the data in the
> target system is as per expectation after loading.
>
> The common tests that can be performed for this are as follows −
>
> Checking Aggregate functions (sum, max, min, count),
>
> Checking and validating the counts and the actual data between the
> source and the target for columns without transformations or with
> simple transformations.
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/etl_testing/etl_testing_data_completeness.htm

- Count checks if you have all the records
- Summing a column checks of all the values total to the same value on both sides
- Checking a couple of rows checks that the data is not skewed

These checks are really fast even on large datasets.

I think it is a risk-based question, you could develop a tool that checks all the transformations and all the rows, but this would just duplicate the development efforts. It is a Health care project, so if people could die from wrong data, maybe it is worth investing more, if not maybe just do the simple checks.

The tutorialspoint website has a lot of [testing ideas for ETL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/etl_testing/index.htm), it has helped me a lot in the past.